# Is there any modified query for this query:

Tags: database, laravel-4

I am using laravel.In my controller I used a query(given below).Is there any modified query for this?? Or is it okk???

```
$sub = Studentacademicinfo::where('class','=',$cat)->where('section','=',$section)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this if you wanted to tidy up the code:

```
$sub = Studentacademicinfo::whereClass($cat)->whereSection($section)->get();
```

But the resulting SQL will be the same